# how to install red 5(RTMP) in my server?

Tags: apache-flex, rtmp

I have planned to design chat application in flex 3. i need rtmp to be used for it.Now the thing i need is i want to install in my server so that i can be used it for testing i am new to this..can any one say me in detail how to proceed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this section of the Red5 web site?

http://red5.org/wiki/Install

If so, what problems are you having.